# Change Footer in Madrid Theme

Tags: beamer, footer

I am using the `beamer` theme `Madrid`. Is there an easy way to display the institution name instead of the date in the right part of the footer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick hack:

```
\date[Institute]{\today}
```